# Querying an implicit re-orderable list

Tags: sql

I was searching for a way to re-order my records, like blog posts, for instance.

One of the solutions I have found is to self-reference to refer to the previous (or next) value, like in a linked list (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/375246). However, this requires the client-side (a web service or perhaps a mobile app) to implement the linked-list travesal logic to derive the order.

Is there a way to do this at the database level?

The reason for this is that if you are deriving the order at the client-side, then if you want to display only the first 10 records, you would have to retrieve all the records anyway.

EDIT

It seems the blog posts example was a very bad example, sorry. I was thinking of blog posts as they are displayed on an admin dashboard, and the user can re-order the position they are displayed by dragging and dropping. Hope this is more clear.

EDIT 2

I guess, generally, what I'm really asking is, how can one implement and query a tree-like structure in SQL

Comment: Not easy to understand what you mean, maybe you could give some example with sample data and how it should be reordered.

Comment: Blog posts are a rather specific example where it mostly doesn't matter, because users will tend to be content with ordering them by date (ascending or descending, as required) in combination with filtering them by tag. This may not give a series  in order, but that's what separate posts with an index are for. This is the kind of problem that you preferably solve by not solving it unless there's an absolute need -- it's too expensive for a nice-to-have that has to work in all circumstances.

Comment: You can use a recursive query to query  a list that defines the sort order by a self-reference.

Comment: Your question is very vague. Do you have your posts stored as a linked list? If not, you could a `sortorder` integer column to the posts table. Put the order of the post in there and use `ORDER BY sortorder` to retrieve the post sorted by this order. You can always change the order by changing the values of `sortorder`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+recursive-query